# changing of text color and image background color using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i want to write a script for changing of text color and image color on click .. here i want to call the external style sheets (which i ll be creating) to the function .. each color ll be ve ng differnt .css page. so that when i click the orange color the text and the image background should change to to the orange color if i click to red it should change to red..can anyone pls help me out in dis.. any ideas or sugessions... thanks in advance.

Comment: Your English is hard to interpret. I gave up after reading 3 times. Please write normal sentences with full words and if necessary run a spellchecker. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Define each colour as a class in your CSS:

```
.red {
color: red;
}

.blue {
color: blue;
}
```

Then set a click attribute in your HTML:

```
<p onclick="javascript: this.setAttribute('class', 'red');">Click to make me red</p>
<p onclick="javascript: this.setAttribute('class', 'blue');">Click to make me blue</p>
```

There are optimisations not described here - using unobtrusive javascript mainly - but this should give you a start.